# Xml Response in web api mvc

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api

Getting `XML` in `Web API` response in a single object having string format. but I got an issue in that `XML` while running in `postman`, it got values like

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"cda.xsl\"?>\r\n<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:sdtc=\"urn:hl7-org:sdtc\" moodCode=\"EVN\" xmlns=\"urn:hl7-org:v3\">\r\n  <realmCode code=\"US\" />\r\n  <typeId root=\"2.16.840.1.113883.1.3\" extension=\"POCD_HD000040\" />\r\n  <templateId root=\"2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1\" extension=\"2015-08-01\" />\r\n  <templateId root=\"2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2\" extension=\"2015-08-01\" />\r\n  <id root=\"2.16.840.1.113883.3.9999999989\" extension=\"EP_CCD_2017-November\" />\r\n  <code code=\"3
```

it should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cda.xsl"?><ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" moodCode="EVN" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">  <realmCode code="US" />  <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040" />  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1" extension="2015-08-01" />  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2" extension="2015-08-01" />  <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.9999999989" extension="EP_CCD_2017-November" />  <code code="3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Postman is [escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the characters**

Postman escapes the `"` character by placing a `\` before it.

This should not form a problem with parsing in ASP.Net Web Api.

Comment: Thank You.I got it.